# Sql server equivalent for this mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2005, equivalent

I ve formatted a date column in mysql like `DATE_FORMAT(enquiry.enquiryDate,'%d-%b-%Y') as enquiryDate` and now i want sql server equivalent for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can see an example with convert use here :

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

or examples using a function here:

http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/

```
SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (getdate(), ‘MM/DD/YYYY’)           – 01/03/2012

SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (getdate(), ‘DD/MM/YYYY’)           – 03/01/2012

SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (getdate(), ‘M/DD/YYYY’)            – 1/03/2012

SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (getdate(), ‘M/D/YYYY’)             – 1/3/2012

SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (getdate(), ‘M/D/YY’)               – 1/3/12

SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (getdate(), ‘MM/DD/YY’)             – 01/03/12

SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (getdate(), ‘MON DD, YYYY’)         – JAN 03, 2012

SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (getdate(), ‘Mon DD, YYYY’)         – Jan 03, 2012

SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (getdate(), ‘Month DD, YYYY’)       – January 03, 2012

SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (getdate(), ‘YYYY/MM/DD’)           – 2012/01/03

SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (getdate(), ‘YYYYMMDD’)             – 20120103

SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (getdate(), ‘YYYY-MM-DD’)           – 2012-01-03

– CURRENT_TIMESTAMP returns current system date and time in standard internal format

SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,‘YY.MM.DD’)      – 12.01.03

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CONVERT` function - for example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 106)
```

There's a list of formats here:

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

And some more information here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx